# How to get column count in SQL before executing the query? i.e. way other than ResultSetMetaData

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a sql query. Because of too many BO's are involved, it's forming very big query containing more than 1000 columns. So I need some way with which I can find column count before hand and then apply some logic to handle 1000 column error.

May be parsing a query to get column count would help. But not getting how to implement it.

Note: tried below code already, it's giving me result, but i dont want to execute query, that's costly.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = pstmt.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(meta.getColumnCount());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `LIMIT`?

Comment: 'LIMIT' is for rows not for columns. @ThomasEdwin

Comment: ThomasEdwin's idea is that with `where rownum = 0` there is nothing costly, because you retrieve zero rows (which the DBMS detects immediately), so you only get the mere column information.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Can you elaborate how to do that? Note: query is formed dynamically so don't have control over a query, so only once query is formed I can check column count just that I don't want to use ResultSetMetaData.

Comment: I do not think so, that run the query even with some limitations is proper solution.

Comment: If you get the complete query, that would be difficult, because you'd have to find the main where clause. So maybe not the best option. And you are right, you should be able to get the column information without having to run the query. AFAIK the app sends the query to the DBMS, the DBMS says Okay and gives the column Information, then the app says "run the query" and fetches the results. So there is a point before running the query where the app should be given the column Information, but I don't know how to do this in Java. I would have thought the code you are showing does exactly that.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Thanks for quick response. You have exactly understood my concern here. Can you please suggest how can I parse the query in order to get column count?

Comment: By preparing the statement you are not executing it, so the cost you think is there doesn't exist.

Comment: A non-exact method would be to get the substring between SELECT and FROM and count the number of commas that occur. Not very precise but it will get you very close. I'd try @MarkRotteveel's suggestion first; double check that simply preparing the statement doesn't incur a cost before you spend a lot of time fiddling with parsing SQL.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel isn't it internally executing it while getting resultsetmetadata?

Comment: @Shitalb1 As far as I know, no it doesn't. If it would, that would be pretty illogical, because some queries can have side-effects and most prepared statements actually require parameters before execution. The metadata comes available from preparing (parsing/compiling) the statement.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a plain old select query like :

`select col1,col2 as xyz, col3,col4... from ... where ...`

you can do something like this:

```
String select="select";//"SELECT" if yours is in caps
String from="from";//"FROM" if yours is in caps
String cols = sql.substring(sql.indexOf(select)+select.length(), sql.indexOf(from)); 
int colCount = cols.split(",").length;
```

If your query contains functions like `fn(col,'blah blah')` you need to write some extra code to ID such functions and process things appropriately.

Comment: Yes it is solution described in comment in earlier post but I think that if programmer know algorithm of query creation (concating) he should count columns during creation and not concat the query in some part of code and later parse them...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your SQL query using lot of wildcards after SELECT statement right? If no wildcard used, you can parse SQL query part between SELECT and FROM to get column numbers.I feel some disturbance in the force if i hear you have such big results of unknown attributes. If we can say that SQL table is data source, we can say that query result is data source too. In case of SQL table we have defined very specifically what columns(attributes) it contain. If u create SQL query without specification of columns you have data source of unknown entity. Are you trying to create some BI system? If yes you should consider to get metadata of table and create specific query based on this informations.

Comment: Query is fetching data from different tables and columns and displaying on UI, so those many columns are bound to fetch through the query. Also there is hyperlink for some column values which are responsible to fetch more columns, so it can not be avoided. If you have any idea, Can you please suggest how can I parse the query part between select and from?

Comment: I still think that if you are able to create SQL query some way (some generic based on users selection via UI or simple writing it) you have ways to get all you need. Of cource that my opinion is based on good parctises (do not let user write SQL querie etc.). Despite the fact what i think, simpliest way to parse columns (and get its count) is very very nasty:
    String[] column = sql.substring(sql.indexOf("SELECT") + 6, sql.indexOf("FROM")).split(",")